# No DOCTYPE declaration error in JDOM

Tags: java, jdom, jdom-2

My code is below

```
Document convertDataToXML(ArrayList<MyData> oMyDataCollection) {
    try {

            //get the Input template file location          
            String sExportXMLTemplate = "";
            XPathFactory xpfacFile = XPathFactory.instance();
            XPathExpression<Element> xElementsLoc = xpfacFile.compile(IssueExchangerXPathConstants.EXPORT_XML_TEMPLATE, Filters.element());
            List<Element> elementsLoc = xElementsLoc.evaluate(xConfigurationDocument);          
            for (Element xElem : elementsLoc) {     
                logger.trace(xElem.getText());
                logger.trace("getXSLTFileName ends");
                sExportXMLTemplate =xElem.getText();
                break;
            }           
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("C://Folder/Template.xml"));
            DOMBuilder domBuilder = new DOMBuilder();
            //Document xIssuesMappingXMLInternal=null;
            Document xIssuesMappingXMLInternal;
            xIssuesMappingXMLInternal = domBuilder.build(doc);              
            XPathFactory xpfac = XPathFactory.instance();       
            XPathExpression<Element> xElements = xpfac.compile(ExportXMLConstants.ISSUES_EXPORT,Filters.element(),null);
            List<Element> elements = xElements.evaluate(xIssuesMappingXMLInternal);
            for (Element xIssuesParent : elements) {
              System.out.println(xIssuesParent.getName());
              Element xCloneIssue = null ; 
              int iCounter=1;
              for (Element xIssueChild : xIssuesParent.getChildren())
              {
                  xCloneIssue = xIssueChild.clone();
                  xCloneIssue.detach();
                  xIssueChild.detach(); //remove from parent
                  break; //expecting only one node here..
              }
            //LOOP THE COLLECTION                
             Element xClonedCopy = xCloneIssue.clone();
             for (RTCData oMyDataCollection : oMyDataCollectionCollection) {                 
                 xCloneIssue.getAttribute(ExportXMLConstants.ISSUE_ID_ATTR_EXPORT).setValue("ISSUE-"+iCounter);
                //fill other nodes
                 Element xNewID = xCloneIssue.getChild(ExportXMLConstants.ISSUE_NEW_ID_EXPORT);
                 xNewID.setText(oMyDataCollection.getsExchangePartnerID());                  
                 Element xID = xCloneIssue.getChild(ExportXMLConstants.ISSUE_ID_EXPORT);
                 xID.setText(oMyDataCollection.getsID_Issue());                  
                 Element xSummary = xCloneIssue.getChild(ExportXMLConstants.ISSUE_SUMMARY_EXPORT);
                 xSummary.setText(oMyDataCollection.getsSummary_ExchangeInfo());                     
                 Element xStatus = xCloneIssue.getChild(ExportXMLConstants.ISSUE_STAUTS_EXPORT);
                 xStatus.setText(oMyDataCollection.getsStatus_Issue());                  
                 Element xComments = xCloneIssue.getChild(ExportXMLConstants.ISSUE_COMMENTS_EXPORT);
                 if (xComments != null)
                 {
                     Element xComment = xComments.getChild(ExportXMLConstants.ISSUE_COMMENT_EXPORT);                         
                     xComment.setText(oMyDataCollection.getsFeedback());
                 }
                 xIssuesParent.addContent(xCloneIssue);
                 xCloneIssue=xClonedCopy.clone();
                 iCounter++;
              }
            }
            XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();                 
            // display nice nice
            xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
            xmlOutput.output(xIssuesMappingXMLInternal, new FileWriter("c:\\temp\\OutputFile.xml"));
            //logger.info(xmlOutput.outputString(xIssuesMappingXMLInternal));
            //logger.info(xIssuesMappingXMLInternal.toString());
            return xIssuesMappingXMLInternal;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.fatal(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The purpose of this function is to convert data from object to XML and return the XML Document. To verify this "Document" I am saving the generated XML to a file `c:\temp\OutputFile.xml` & I get the XML as I need

But when i try to return the Document which is `xIssuesMappingXMLInternal` I always get the following `Document: No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is element <ISSUES/>`

Why is this c

The XML looks like below

```
<ISSUES>
   <ISSUE ID="123">
      <NEWID>123</NEWID>
      <ID>233</ID>
      <SUMMARY>THIS IS A TEST</SUMMARY>
      <STATUS>NEW</STATUS>
      <COMMENTS>
        <COMMENT>
            PLAIN TEXT DATA HERE
        </COMMENT>
      </COMMENTS>
   </ISSUE>
   <ISSUE>
        .....
  </ISSUE>
</ISSUES>
```

Here I will have multiple  nodes

My expectation is that the Document would return the whole ISSUES node.

Also I don't want to use any "doctype" here. it's a simple XML

I am using Java SE 1.6 with JDOM 2.0.4

Any help would be really appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: please update yor question and add the full stacktrace for the error, and mark the exact line in the code which failed... thanks

Comment: It doesn't fail but the return value if `document` is `Document: No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is element <ISSUES/>` which I cannot use it further. As a workaround, I am a saving this `document` to a file and then reading the file instead of passing the document object

Comment: Edited the answer below

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I am getting the same error and unable to use the Document.

Comment: I haven't tried after this point as I resorted to a workaround

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you have the DOCTYPE problem. I will try to reproduce it later. In the interim, it will probably go away when you change the lines:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(
               new File("C://Folder/Template.xml"));
        DOMBuilder domBuilder = new DOMBuilder();
        //Document xIssuesMappingXMLInternal=null;
        Document xIssuesMappingXMLInternal;
        xIssuesMappingXMLInternal = domBuilder.build(doc);
```

to

```
        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document xIssuesMappingXMLInternal = saxBuilder.build(
               new File("C://Folder/Template.xml"));
```

There is no need to use a DOM intermediate document when using JDOM

EDIT: (Based on comments above)
The real issue is not an issue, it is 'just working'. What you are seeing is the result of the [toString() method call on Document](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/Document.java#L629): You just did not copy/paste the [] braces which would have made that more obvious, and I would not have been confused.

Everything is working just fine, and, if you want the output of the XML document as a String value (instead of just the toString() value of the Document), then use [XMLOutputter.outputString(doc)](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html#outputString%28org.jdom2.Document%29)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try & give you a feedback. Also I am trying to return the `Document` as I want to use this in memory `Document` to convert this to another format using a XSLT

Comment: tied and still the same result `[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <ISSUES/>]]`

Comment: Tried with JDOM 2.0.5, still same result :-(